# meteor reactive content filtering

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a dynamic page with a table of data, that needs filtering.
I have month field for every item in my collection, I also have a select with 13 options (12 months + any), I have it working if the query gets called again, however it's not dynamic. Here's what I have right now:

HTML

```
     <h4>Filter by Month</h4>
  <select class="form-control month-filter">
    <option value="show_m_any">Any</option>
    <option value="show_m_1">January</option>
    <option value="show_m_2">Februray</option>
    <option value="show_m_3">March</option>
    <option value="show_m_4">April</option>
    <option value="show_m_5">May</option>
    <option value="show_m_6">June</option>
    <option value="show_m_7">July</option>
    <option value="show_m_8">August</option>
    <option value="show_m_9">September</option>
    <option value="show_m_10">October</option>
    <option value="show_m_11">November</option>
    <option value="show_m_12">December</option>
 </select>
  {{#each tripList}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{day}}.{{month}}.{{year}}</td>
        <td>{{car}}</td>
        <td>{{a}}</td>
        <td>{{b}}</td>
        <td>{{dist}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="delete-trip"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
      </tr> 
    {{/each}}
```

main.js (client)

```
Template.trip_html.helpers({
trip_html: function(){

console.log(Trips.find({}))
return Trips.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 10});
},

tripList: function(){
if(month_filter == 1){
    return Trips.find({"month": { $eq: "1" }}, {sort:{createdAt: -1}});
} else if(month_filter == 2){
    return Trips.find({"month": { $eq: "2" }}, {sort:{createdAt: -1}});
} else {
  return Trips.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
}

}});


Template.trip_html.events({
 "change .month-filter": function( event, template ) {
    var value = $( event.target ).val();
    switch(value){
    case "show_m_any":
    month_filter = 0;
    break;

    case "show_m_1":
    month_filter = 1;
    break;

    case "show_m_2":
    month_filter = 2;
    break; 

    case "show_m_3":
    break;

        case "show_m_4":
    break;

        case "show_m_5":
    break;

        case "show_m_6":
    break;

        case "show_m_7":
    break;

        case "show_m_8":
    break;

        case "show_m_9":
    break;

        case "show_m_10":
    break;

        case "show_m_11":
    break;

         case "show_m_12":
    break;

    }
  }});
```

Image of the page
[image: Pic1]

[image: Filtering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [reactive variable](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html):

First of all, change the `value` of your `option` tags to just the `number` of the month.

Example:

```
<select class="form-control month-filter">
    <option value="0">Any</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">Februray</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    [ ... etc ... ]
 </select>
```

Then in your events block you don't need to use a `switch` because you can just pull the month number straight from your option `value`.

```
Template.trip_html.events({
    "change .month-filter": function( event, template ) {

        const month = new ReactiveVar(null); //declare reactive var
        var monthNumber = $( event.target ).val(); // get month number from selected option value
        month.set(monthNumber); // set reactive var to month number
});
```

Then in your helper you only need:

```
tripList: function(){
    const monthNumber = month.get()
    return Trips.find({"month": { $eq: monthNumber }}, {sort:{createdAt: -1}});
}
```